# Divide columns in a DataFrame by a Series (result is only NaNs?)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I'm trying to do a similar thing to what is posted in this question: [Python Pandas - n X m DataFrame multiplied by 1 X m Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563934/python-pandas-n-x-m-dataframe-multiplied-by-1-x-m-dataframe)

I have an n x m DataFrame, with all non-zero float values, and a 1 x m column, with all non-zero float values, and I'm trying to divide each column in the n x m dataframe by the values in the column.

So I've got:

```
a      b      c
1      2      3
4      5      6
7      8      9
```

and

```
x
11
12
13
```

and I'm looking to return:

```
a      b     c
1/11   2/11  3/11
4/12   5/12  6/12
7/13   8/13  9/13
```

I've tried a multiplication operation first, to see if I can make it work, so I tried applying the two solutions given in the answer to the question above.

```
df_prod = pd.DataFrame({c:df[c]* df_1[c].ix[0] for c in df.columns})
```

This produces a "Key Error 0"
And using the other solution to :

```
df.mul(df_1.iloc[0])
```

This just gives me all NaN, although in the right shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of NaNs are due to misalignment of your indexes. To get over this, you will either need to divide by numpy arrays,

```
# <=0.23
df.values / df2[['x']].values  # or df2.values assuming there's only 1 column
# 0.24+
df.to_numpy() / df[['x']].to_numpy()

array([[0.09090909, 0.18181818, 0.27272727],
       [0.33333333, 0.41666667, 0.5       ],
       [0.53846154, 0.61538462, 0.69230769]])
```

Or perform an axis aligned division using `.div`:

```
df.div(df2['x'], axis=0)
          a         b         c
0  0.090909  0.181818  0.272727
1  0.333333  0.416667  0.500000
2  0.538462  0.615385  0.692308
```

Comment: Thanks! The second of those works perfectly. The first option tells me it cannot converge the series, and seems to be applying the columns to the rows, somehow.

Comment: @Tom ye, realised the first one was wrong. Fixed with a numpy solution. Go with the second, though.

Comment: Thanks - great help!

Comment: df2 has only single column `x`. Is there any reason you use `df2[['x']].values` instead of `df2.values` ?

Comment: @AndyL. Yes, because `df2[['x']].values` will also work when `df2` has more than one column (`df2.values` won't).

Comment: ah, you want to keep the solution generalized.

Comment: @AndyL. As much as I humanly can. Sometimes the benefit of generalised code is lost on OPs, who usually go for the lazy but functional solution even if it only works for their data. I keep future readers in mind ;-)