# How to divide pandas data frame by pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and series

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,6,9,8]})
series = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
```

I want to get a data `answer` frame that is equivalent to

```
answer = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 'B': [5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0]})
```

from `df` and `series`. It doesn't seem like I can just do `answer = df/series`. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: It is [`df.div(series, axis=0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56692532/4909087)

Comment: well that's the answer but Anonymous can't accept a comment :)